# Label field issue - OpenErp

Tags: python, xml, view, orm, odoo

I need to show the `label` or `title` of a field in OpenErp.

I have a piece of code in the `purchase` module that retrieves `company_id, partner_id, date_order, etc` from the form, and then show these fields values in a concatenated way:

```
def _combinalos(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, args, context=None):
    values = {}
    for id in ids:
        rec = self.browse(cr, uid, [id], context=context)[0]
        values[id] = {}
        values[id] = '0%s-%s%s-%s-%s' %(rec.company_id, rec.partner_id, rec.soli_cant, rec.dest, rec.date_order)
    return values
```

Then i call this function like:

```
        'nombre' : fields.function(_combinalos, type='char', string='Nombre', arg=('empresa','provee','soli_cant', 'dest', 'anho'), method=True),
```

And of course the XML view code:

```
<h1>
    <label string="Request for Quotation " attrs="{'invisible': [('state','not in',('draft','sent'))]}"/>
    <label string="Purchase Order " attrs="{'invisible': [('state','in',('draft','sent'))]}"/>
    <field name="nombre" class="oe_inline" readonly="1" />
</h1>
```

Being `nombre` the function field.

Problem is, when i save the document, it should show me the names or labels for these fields, but just shows me like the ID of the field or something:

[image]

So, how could i show the 'name' or 'label' for these fiels? Is it maybe some attribute in the xml field call?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1)Lable is not display may be because you not specified " `for` " attribute use it like

```
<h1>
    <label string="Request for Quotation " for="nombre" attrs="{'invisible': [('state','not in',('draft','sent'))]}"/>
    <label string="Purchase Order " for="nombre" attrs="{'invisible': [('state','in',('draft','sent'))]}"/>
    <field name="nombre" class="oe_inline" readonly="1" />
</h1>
```

or may be you use a class `oe_editonly` in div out side h1 tag like .

```
<div class="oe_title">
    <div class="oe_edit_only">
       <h1> Your code </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will display a label in edit mode only, once you save a record label becomes invisible.

**2)Problem is, when i save the document, it should show me the names or labels for these fields, but just shows me like the ID of the field or something:**

it is because the problem in your function `_combinalos` return browse object rec.company_id that is return a browse object of company if you want `id` you should return rec.company_id.id like

```
def _combinalos(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, args, context=None):
     values = {}
     for id in ids:
         rec = self.browse(cr, uid, [id], context=context)[0]
         values[id] = {}
         values[id] = '0%s-%s%s-%s-%s' %(rec.company_id.id, rec.partner_id.id, rec.soli_cant, rec.dest, rec.date_order)
    return values
```

Comment: Thank you very very much, works perfectly, btw, is there a way to show just the 'year' part in 'date_order'? Just '2013' for example, and not '2013-09-23'?

Comment: 'date_order' is 'date' type field

Comment: use rec.date_order.year for more information on datetime refere http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Btw it says it has no attribute 'year', in the case of 'date_order' format